# Can I add a web page to an e-mail message in Microsoft Outlook 2003?

Tags: asp.net, email, outlook-2003

How can we add a web page or a Windows Forms to the Outlook mail so that when I send a mail to a person he/she should be able to enter the data in the controls on the mail form?

The user should also have the ability to save the data directly from the mail, instead of opening my web or a Windows application and update the data.

Comment: Apart from *how* to do it, *why* would you want to do it? I assume that with people having their inboxes flooded with spam these days, you'd hardly find anybody filling in information in a HTML-mail and sending it out to an unknown page.

Comment: what we used to do was for our customers to update reports and stuff we provided them with a link in thier mail, through which they used to fill out the information and update the reports.Instead of going to another page to fill out this info just wanted to know if it is possible to load the webform directly.Hope i am clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the menu option "Tools->Forms->Design a Form"

A nice tutorial is at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA012106101033.aspx